# Getting error while running scala test runner

Tags: scala, scalatest

Any idea on why am i getting this error while running a scala test,

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: ERROR: -r has been deprecated for a very long time and is no longer supported, to prepare for reusing it for a different purpose in the near future. Please change all uses of -r to -C.
at org.scalatest.tools.ArgsParser$.checkArgsForValidity(ArgsParser.scala:41)
at org.scalatest.tools.Runner$.runOptionallyWithPassFailReporter(Runner.scala:857)
at org.scalatest.tools.Runner$.run(Runner.scala:850)
at org.scalatest.tools.Runner.run(Runner.scala)
at org.jetbrains.plugins.scala.testingSupport.scalaTest.ScalaTestRunner.runScalaTest2(ScalaTestRunner.java:141)
at org.jetbrains.plugins.scala.testingSupport.scalaTest.ScalaTestRunner.main(ScalaTestRunner.java:32)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:134)
```

Is this an issue with my dependancies got updated itself? Because this test was ran earlier without any issues.

Comment: Has the directory name or directory path changed?

Comment: No, i didnt do such changes. @notionquest

Comment: Have you find a solution? I would ask you how you run your tests (maven, gradle, sbt, IDE). The error says an option `-r` is being used and it's deprecated - now it should use `-C`. Depending the libs that were updated, this may be the cause. If you found the problem, please post here.

Comment: Hey @Tom,  It worked fine when i did project reimport in my IDE. Not sure what went wrong in this. So i couldnt post any answer for this. Thanks for asking Tom.

Comment: I have the same issue. The issue is that "-r" ISN'T actually being used! It does this even though "-C" was actually the option passed in.